# HTML sanitizer using regex & security issues

Tags: php, html, regex, sanitization, whitelist

I know that parsing HTML with regexp **is bad**, and it can not work for all cases (there are plenty topics about that on Stack Overflow).
But I still wanted to try to sanitize HTML with regex based on a whitelist method.

I would like to show you my code bellow (written in PHP 5.2).
It seems to work fine, but I'm still wondering if there are security issues.

So, did I got something wrong ?

Basic principle is to use Html_Sanitizer::sanitize()

1. The function first replaces allowed tags with no attributes with tokens. Then parse for tags with attributes and replace them with token too.
2. The HTML tags are then parsed to detect the allowed attributes (using the cleanTag function). The HTML tag is therefore re-builded in a (lets-hope) safe way.
3. htmlspecialchars is used to be sure that remaining code is clean
4. tokens are replaced with safe tags.

Code:

```
class Html_Sanitizer
{
    const VALIDATOR_CSS_UNIT = '(([\+\-]?[0-9\.]+)(em|ex|px|in|cm|mm|pt|pc|\%))|0';
    const VALIDATOR_URL = 'http://\\S+';
    const VALIDATOR_CSS_PROPERTY = '[a-z\-]+';
    const VALIDATOR_STYLE = '[^"]*';

    protected static $_tags = 'a|b|blockquote|br|cite|d[ldt]|h[1-6]|i|img|li|ol|p|span|strong|u|ul';

    protected static $_attributes = array(
        'img' => array(
            'width' => '[0-9]+',
            'height' => '[0-9]+',
            'src' => self::VALIDATOR_URL,
            'style' => self::VALIDATOR_STYLE
            ),
        'span' => array(
            'style' => self::VALIDATOR_STYLE
            ),
        'p' => array(
            'style' => self::VALIDATOR_STYLE
            ),
        'a' =>  array(
            'href' => self::VALIDATOR_URL
            )
    );

    protected static $_styleValidators = array(
        'color' => '(\#[a-fA-F0-9]+)|([a-z ]+)',
        'background-color' => '\#[a-zA-Z0-9]+',
        'font-style' => '(normal|italic|oblique)',
        'font-size' => '[\-a-z]+',
        'margin-left' => self::VALIDATOR_CSS_UNIT,
        'margin-right' => self::VALIDATOR_CSS_UNIT,
        'text-align' => '(left|right|center|justify)',
        'text-indent' => self::VALIDATOR_CSS_UNIT,
        'text-decoration' => '(none|overline|underline|blink|line-through)',
        'width' => self::VALIDATOR_CSS_UNIT,
        'height' => self::VALIDATOR_CSS_UNIT
    );

    public static function sanitize($str)
    {
        $tokens = array();

        //tokenize opening tags with no attributes
        $pattern = '#<(/)?('. self::$_tags .')>#';
        $replace = '__SAFE_TAG_$1$2__';
        $str = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);

        // tokenize tags with attributes
        $pattern = '#<('. self::$_tags .')(?:\s+(?:[a-z]+)="(?:[^"\\\]*(?:\\\"[^"\\\]*)*)")*\s*(/)?>#';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        foreach($matches as $i => $match) {
            $tokens[$i] = self::cleanTag($match[1], $match[0]);
            $str = str_replace($match[0], '__SAFE_TOKEN_'.$i.'__', $str);
        }

        $str = htmlspecialchars($str);

        foreach ($tokens as $i => $cleanTag) {
            $str = str_replace('__SAFE_TOKEN_'.$i.'__', $cleanTag, $str);
        }

        $pattern = '#__SAFE_TAG_(/?(?:'. self::$_tags .'))__#';
        $replace = '<$1>';
        $str = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);

        return $str;
    }

    public static function cleanTag($tag, $str)
    {
        $cleanTag = '<' . $tag;

        if ($tag === 'a') {
            $cleanTag .= ' rel="nofolow" target="_blank"';
        }

        if (isset(self::$_attributes[$tag])) {
            foreach(self::$_attributes[$tag] as $attr => $attrPattern) {
                $pattern = '#'.$attr.'="('. $attrPattern .')"#';
                preg_match($pattern, $str, $match);
                if (isset($match[1])) {
                    if ($attr == 'style') {
                        $cleanTag .= ' style="' . self::cleanStyle($match[1]) . '"';
                    } else {
                        $cleanTag .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $match[1] . '"';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($tag === 'img') {
            $cleanTag .= ' /';
        }

        $cleanTag .= '>';
        return $cleanTag;
    }

    public static function cleanStyle($style)
    {
        $cleanStyle = '';

        foreach(self::$_styleValidators as $stl => $stlPattern) {
            $pattern = '#[; ]?' . $stl . '\s*:\s*(' . $stlPattern . ')\s*;#i';
            preg_match($pattern, $style, $match);
            if (isset($match[1])) {
                $cleanStyle .= ($cleanStyle ? ' ' : '') . $stl . ':' . $match[1] . ';';
            }
        }

        return $cleanStyle;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Please*, don't go there. Go here instead: http://htmlpurifier.org/.

Comment: Whitelisting is a perfectly valid approach. Looks ok, the back and forth rewriting with a `__SAFE_TAG_` marker however is inapt. And I would agree that it's not a sensible use of time when HTML_Purifier already exists, which covers all the edge cases.

Comment: Thanx for the comment, but codding is not just a question of time. Sometimes it's also about fun. And I like codding, it helps me to better understand what other people did, and where the real issues are. Furthermore, I'm developping for three years now, I used a lot of frameworks, and at the end I always had to do it myself because a bug was not planned to be corrected and it took me more time to patch an existing framwork than devlopping my own that exactly match what I need. But yes you're right, I should not do this :)

Answer (score 0):

I can use the style related attributes to deface your site. And in some browsers, to crash the browser by setting a huge width and height combo.

I can use styles to do even more defacing.

I can use the image SRC attribute to track your users movements. To spy on them and to make money.

These are all things I can do with your class if you coded it PERFECTLY as intended. Which odds are you didn't and there are probably other holes that open access to even more devious things.

Comment: Ok thanx for the width and height. I should add some additionnal validators. I know style is a bit touchy, I should be more carrefull on that part. But I'm sorry (I'm french), I don't understand your last sentence. What do you mean by "I didn't coded perfectly as intended". Do you mean there is a difference between what I explained, and what I actually coded ?

Comment: No. I did not look at your code. I just assumed it was what you said it was. I was suggesting that you are trying to fix a problem that is a moving target and is fundamentally impossible to solve.